# How to change android 2.1 themes

Tags: android, themes

Hi
I just bought xperia x10 and upgraded it to android 2.1 but I am struggling with themes. I have downloaded couple of them from the market but I do not know how to install them. How do I change themes for andorid 2.1?

Comment: Belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: This type of question might be a bit off-topic for this site. This site is mainly for programming questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that site existed. It is just I have been searching for hours without any luck and that is why I asked here. Thank you very much for the website again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, I think this is the wrong place for your question.  But themes are usually not stand alone.  Look at the market page for the themes you downloaded and find out what home replacement it uses, then download that from the market.

Most common that include full themes would be PandaHome, Ahome, etc.  Read the full description on the theme page, it will tell you which one.

Comment: Thank you. I read the market page for the themes I downloaded, they did not explain the installation procedure I guess I downloaded the wrong ones

Answer (score 0):

in my experience to install android theme such as Sticker Album, I only need to download it and install it as usual.

But for some android not all [android themes](http://alltemaandroid.blogspot.com/search/label/tema%20android) can be installed to your device...
So, I advice you to [download tema android](http://alltemaandroid.blogspot.com/2013/11/download-tema-android-sticker-album.html) that supported by your devise...